# Telegram bot method SendContact not have add button

Tags: telegram-bot

I use the telegram bot api method `SendContact` for sharing contacts to user.

```
Telegram.Bot.Api Bot = GetTelegramBot();
Bot.SendContact(chatID, phone, "FirstName");
```

The message with contact is sent, but it hasn't an add button. Is it possible to realize an add button in this process and when user press it, then the recieved contact would be added to his contacts list?

Comment: Do you mean direct to his contacts?
This can not be done